# How to reproduce bin folder in Eclipse after it is deleted?

Tags: eclipse, build

I'm switching out of Net Beans (since Netbeans intellisense speed was too fast for my patience). However, my habit since NetBeans age driving me nut with new Eclipse.
Normally, when some thing is wrong inside Netbeans auto compile mechanism, I just go to build folder located under the project root and delete it (sometimes with Unlocker), then Net Beans will recreated that folder and put .class file into. However, recently, when I tried to do the same thing with bin folder under Eclipse project root, the bin folder will not be reproduced, even if I restart the IDE, turn off Build Automatically, and run Build All (Ctrl+B).

Comment: Since Eclipse won't deliver any .class file to bin folder, I cannot do anything else. No unit test run, no Class.main method run. Ouch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that `bin` is not your class output folder. You should check in `Project properties|Java Build Path|Source`.

Comment: This should do it, Eclipse will automatically create and hide your output folder (it's filtered by default).  You can customize the filters if you want to show it.

Comment: I think that bin should be my output folder because when I use Project>Clean... then the folder is re-created (after I deleted it).

Comment: So the folder is being re-created with nothing in it? Have you (a) checked from outside Eclipse and (b) checked for view filtering in Eclipse?

Comment: Ouch, I checked Project Properties|Java Build Path and found out that I had added bin to Source list (although at the same time bin was also the output folder). Removing bin from Source entries list solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

In the menu, don't turn off automatic build and click Project > Clean...

Comment: It does some help. But the xml files that I created inside src folder are not copied to bin folder.

Comment: Note my other comment. If these files were created outside of Eclipse, Eclipse won't be aware of them until you F5.

Comment: Can you have a look at this screen shot: http://seamoo.com/Eclipse-Screen-3.jpg. I think Eclipse is keeping track of these xml files. I press F5 (and Context Menu>Refresh) several times but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not related to this problem, but something you need to be aware of is that Eclipse lies about the contents of its folders. More precisely, it reports the contents of internal models of all folders (i.e. contained files and sub-folders) and only refreshes that internal view when you explicitly refresh the view in the GUI.

Especially when you manipulate files outside of Eclipse or using tools started from Eclipse but not directly tied into Eclipse, there WILL be differences Eclipse doesn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that your project does not have "Java nature." Are you seeing source packages in the Package Explorer?

If not, this stanza should appear (or go) in your .project file:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Comment: This solved it for me. Importantly, I had the maven2Nature, nature, before the Java nature... this stopped files from popping out into the bin dir.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to recreate the bin folder directly on the file system and performed a refresh on the eclipse project?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `.project` file should contain at minimum:

```
</projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
```

PS. For standard java project